# Error: BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(): 401 ERROR

Tags: node.js, docker, botframework, microsoft-graph-api

One of a sudden adapter.processActivity fails with these two error messages when sending a chat-message to the bot:

**1. Error Message:**

```
JwtTokenExtractor.getIdentity:err! ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
dev_server        |     at /var/huforce/node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:484:17
...
dev_server        |     at /var/huforce/node_modules/botframework-connector/lib/auth/openIdMetadata.js:14:71
dev_server        |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
dev_server        |     at __awaiter (/var/huforce/node_modules/botframework-connector/lib/auth/openIdMetadata.js:10:12)
dev_server        |     at OpenIdMetadata.getKey (/var/huforce/node_modules/botframework-connector/lib/auth/openIdMetadata.js:30:16)
dev_server        |     at JwtTokenExtractor.<anonymous> (/var/huforce/node_modules/botframework-connector/lib/auth/jwtTokenExtractor.js:86:56)
```

**2. Error Message:**

```
(node:18) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(): 401 ERROR
dev_server        |  ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
dev_server        |     at /var/huforce/node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:484:17
dev_server        |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
dev_server        |     at fetch (/var/huforce/node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:477:12)
dev_server        |     at OpenIdMetadata.<anonymous> (/var/huforce/node_modules/botframework-connector/lib/auth/openIdMetadata.js:54:31)
dev_server        |     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
dev_server        |     at /var/huforce/node_modules/botframework-connector/lib/auth/openIdMetadata.js:14:71
dev_server        |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
dev_server        |     at __awaiter (/var/huforce/node_modules/botframework-connector/lib/auth/openIdMetadata.js:10:12)
dev_server        |     at OpenIdMetadata.refreshCache (/var/huforce/node_modules/botframework-connector/lib/auth/openIdMetadata.js:53:16)
dev_server        |     at OpenIdMetadata.<anonymous> (/var/huforce/node_modules/botframework-connector/lib/auth/openIdMetadata.js:34:32)
dev_server        |     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
dev_server        |     at /var/huforce/node_modules/botframework-connector/lib/auth/openIdMetadata.js:14:71
dev_server        |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
dev_server        |     at __awaiter (/var/huforce/node_modules/botframework-connector/lib/auth/openIdMetadata.js:10:12)
dev_server        |     at OpenIdMetadata.getKey (/var/huforce/node_modules/botframework-connector/lib/auth/openIdMetadata.js:30:16)
dev_server        |     at JwtTokenExtractor.<anonymous> (/var/huforce/node_modules/botframework-connector/lib/auth/jwtTokenExtractor.js:86:56)
dev_server        |     at BotFrameworkAdapter.<anonymous> (/var/huforce/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/botFrameworkAdapter.js:674:27)
dev_server        |     at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
dev_server        |     at rejected (/var/huforce/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/botFrameworkAdapter.js:12:65)
dev_server        |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

**Details:**
I created my bot via the App-Studio. I don't have an azure subscription. I neither use the emulator. The bot runs locally. I am using ngrok to tunnel the requests to my PC. My nodejs-server which hosts the messaging-endpoint runs in a docker container.

**What I have tried:**

- I tried various versions of your (awesome) package
- I checked the client-id & the client-secret
- I created a new client-secret
- I verified my client-id & my client-secret
- I checked my messaging endpoint
- I verified the system time
- I created a new bot via the App Studio and the
- Installing xmlhttprequest manually

**Code:**

```
...
const bot = new Bot();
export const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
  appId: msteams.CLIENT_ID,
  appPassword: msteams.CLIENT_SECRET
});
MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustServiceUrl(
  "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/"
);
...
expressApp.post("/bot", secure((req, res) => {
  
adapter.processActivity(req, res, async context => {  //  <--  error
    await bot.run(context);
  });
}));
```

I am desperate, because we need to deliver a new version of our bot. But, I just can't fix this issue.

I really appreciate any help.

## Edit:

Something strange happened. I have an old docker container from my bot. This version works well. But when running the same old code in a new docker the error occurs. I tried different variants of docker-images. I can't fix this issue.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. For me, it looks like you don't have `XMLHttpRequest` node module installed. Can you possibly share the link to git repo? Plus, I don't think that your problem with the key is relevant, so you can safely remove that part from the question.

Comment: @JurijsKovzels thanks for your reply. Yes, I could verify that these two issues don't correlate. However adding the xmlhttprequest library didn't sove the issue. Please view my edit.